# Implement FlexPaper library in Flex Project

Tags: flex4, flexpaper

I am developing flex pdf reader application using Flexpaper library. I got flexpaper library from http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/download/ and added to my project build path, its working well in both flex web,desktop and mobile project.

I got the source code from http://code.google.com/p/flexpaper/downloads/list and implemented in my flex project to customize the application.

For Flex Desktop project compiled without error but not working correctly. Swf file not loading, always showing spinner in right side.

For Flex Mobile project showing compilation error.
Could not resolve  to a component implementation

Pls give me the solution..

Thanks and Regards 
Dinesh

Answer (score 3):

I got solution. My Flex project and Flex mobile project both are working good with customized flexpaper library.

I changed my code to

```
<mx:VBox xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
         xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
```

Thanks and regards,
Dinesh

Answer (score 2):

Flex Desktop and web project both are compiled and run without error.

I change my code to

```
protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{               myViewer.SwfFile="Paper.swf";                               
}
<flexpaper:FlexPaperViewer id="myViewer" x="10" y="44" >
</flexpaper:FlexPaperViewer>
<s:Button x="306" y="19" label="Load Swf" click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>
```

instead of this

```
<flexpaper:FlexPaperViewer x="10" y="10" height="301" SwfFile="Paper1.swf">
</flexpaper:FlexPaperViewer>
```

For Flex Mobile project showing compilation error. 
Could not resolve  to a component implementation. 
help me